# kindly guide how to make a part of a page user specific in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want a part of a page to be made user specific in `wordpress`. I have tried with available plugins but none could give the required solution. The page is as shown below:

[image: Generic and client Specific]

The client specific features will change as per users. The users should see only their content not of rest.

What shall I do? Thanks.

Comment: then you need to use user roles, divide users as clients and generic while creating the users then you can filter the content accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try to install user role plugin, You can get the result as you mentioned in comments,

[User Role Editor Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/)